# What is the best way to import constants into a groovy script?

Tags: groovy

I have been setting up a scripting envrionment using Groovy.  I have a groovy script called FrameworkiDatabase.groovy which contains a class of the same name.  This works fine.  I also have another file called connections.groovy which contains maps like the following:

```
SUPPORT2=[
 host:"host.name", 
 port:"1521", 
 db:"support2",  
 username:"username", 
 password:"password", 
 dbType:"oracle"
]
```

This holds a collection of database bookmarks, a bit like an oracle tnsnames file, so I don't need to remember all the parameters when connecting to databases.

When using groovysh, I can import this using the load command, and it is available in current scope.  How can I load it as part of a script the same way?  It has no class definition around it - does it need one?  I have tried doing that, and adding a static import, but that didn't work...

I tried something like this, but no luck:

**testFrameworkiDatabase.groovy:**

```
import static connections
def db = new FrameworkiDatabase(SUPPORT2)

db.listInvalidObjects()
db.getDBSchemaVersion()
db.getFWiVersion() 
db.getSPVersion()
db.getFileloaderVersion()
db.getAdminToolVersion()
db.getReportsVersion()
```

So I want to load those connections as constants - is there any way I can do this easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's the **best** way, but one way would be to write this into `Connections.groovy`

```
class Connections {
  static SUPPORT2 = [
    host:"host.name", 
    port:"1521", 
    db:"support2",  
    username:"username", 
    password:"password", 
    dbType:"oracle"
  ]
}
```

Then, compile this with `groovyc Connections.groovy` to generate a class file

Then, in your test script or on the `groovysh` prompt, you can do:

```
import static Connections.*

println SUPPORT2
```

To get the output:

```
[host:host.name, port:1521, db:support2, username:username, password:password, dbType:oracle]
```

If compiling the `Connections.groovy` class isn't good enough, I think you're going to be looking at loading the source into a `Binding` object by using one of the [Groovy embedding techniques](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy)